# Produce loud noise for a security alarm

Tags: speakers, piezo-buzzer

I would like to build a security alarm that just buzzes when a door opens.

My question is can I use a speaker to generate a loud buzzing noise or I need something else like a piezo buzzer?

If I can use the speaker in what way do I have to connect it?

Comment: A speaker needs to be driven by an AC signal. A piezo buzzer has an internal AC generator and a piezo sounder is like a speaker with no ac generator. Here are [two simple circuits](http://www.circuitdb.com/?p=254) that will do what you want - using a (!) 555 timer

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I checked the 2nd circuit and it works great. You can draw that circuit and write it as an answer with a reference. Thank you. :)

Comment: Have you tried the piezo?  They require only voltage to work; no extra circuits.  If so, are they loud enough for your application?

Comment: @SDsolar No I have only used the speaker as I had one available and it worked nicely. I will search for a piezo too. Can you recommend any specifically?

Comment: you can buy battery-drive burgler alarms at the dollar store, they come with magnets, a loud buzzer w/driver, and a reed switch.

Comment: @dandavis I don't want an already built burglar alarm I just wanted to make one because it seems like a fun project.

Comment: @Adam: right, it's just a cheap no-shipping way of getting a single unit buzzer...

Comment: Re " I don't want an already built burglar alarm I just wanted to make one because it seems like a fun project" -> Hooray hooray !!! Welcome to EE :-). ~= how old are you (just approx).
| Look at [these circuits](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=2+transistor+flasher&num=20&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiw0_TE6-fTAhVNO7wKHcXoBJoQsAQIJA&biw=1344&bih=697) - some will drive a speaker directly with minimal parts.

Comment: Ones [like these](https://www.google.co.nz/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fjosepino.com%2Farticles%2Ftransistor%2Fflasher_other.gif&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fjosepino.com%2Fcircuits%2Ftransistor_led_flasher&docid=Yocjrtg7Sk_SXM&tbnid=EyoPOyAIMHYNbM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwiyj_Wo7efTAhUDT7wKHbVYBcwQMwgtKAowCg..i&w=266&h=153&bih=736&biw=1344&q=2%20transistor%20flasher&ved=0ahUKEwiyj_Wo7efTAhUDT7wKHbVYBcwQMwgtKAowCg&iact=mrc&uact=8)
 operate in a way that is not intuitive at a glance. When the upper PNP transistor turns off the + side of the 10 uF falls to ground and the lhs of the cap goes NEGATIVE ...

Comment: ...  and then charges up via the  100k until the cap end reaches about +0.6V and turns on the NPN (lower) transistor. Many people do not realise that it works in that manner.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I am sorry for the late reply but you can add if you want as an answer those schematics included in the link of your comment. They work nicely and they are exactly what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 3):

A speaker by itself will not do anything.  It would require an oscillator circuit to drive it to make a noise.  The same goes for a simple piezo element.

You can buy ready-made buzzers, which just need to be connected to a power supply to work.  These come in a variety of sizes and loudnesses.  Sime will just buzz, others have multi-tone hooters.

Comment: Yup.  Also look for things called "horns".

Comment: @Adam Olin wisely suggests adding an acoustic enhancer to boost loudness. Since you will drive a loudspeaker at a single, fixed frequency, a stiff acoustic resonant cavity will do the same. Many pizeo "buzzers" come mounted in plastic acoustical resonant cavities.

Comment: @glen_geek I have never used an acoustic enhancer. Can you send me any link describing it?

Comment: @Adam The wikipedia page shows how a tuning-fork can excite a wood cavity to enhance audio output: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_resonance  I have enhanced a loudspeaker somewhat by mounting it in a short cylinder. Length affects resonant frequency.